# Indexing into MAtlab table based on max value

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a table T2 with 5 columns and 5 rows. The table columns are 'FirstName','Height','Shoesize','Gender' and 'Profession'.

I have to create a second table containing the 'FirstName','Height' and 'Profession' of the person with the maximum 'Shoesize'.

So far, I found the index of the maximum 'Shoesize'.

`[m,i] = max(T2{:,3})`

However I am struggling to index into the table to abstract the relevant values. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You have extracted the index, so you can directly use that to *index* into the table. Please elaborate on what you exactly do not understand here

Comment: I solved it by myself, thanks!